# Printing everything inside of ssh directory python

Tags: python, ssh

So i need to be able to check version of software on a box, i found a directory where it would be and am trying to ssh into it. So far i can ssh successfully into the box and cd into the dir (i think) how do i print everything in side of that dir. Here is my code

```
 def CheckVersion(ThreadIP,ThreadPw,port,ThreadUser):
      ssh = createSSHClient(ThreadIP,ThreadPw,port,ThreadUser)
      if ssh == 0:
          print "oh crap I just returned 0"
      else:
          stdin,stdout,stderr =  ssh.exec_command("PATH='path' && cd/mnt/soft; cat VERSION")
```

Comment: As an aside, why would it return 0 instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: Because i dont really know haha, i wrote it that way so i can kill threads, this was just a copy of the real funtion that i took alot of things out to make it easier on you guys/girls to help me lol

Comment: You should consider using SFTP rather than plain SSH. SFTP has operations specifically to read directories and files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 stdin,stdout,stderr =  ssh.exec_command("PATH='path' && cd/mnt/soft; ls -LR > contents.txt; cat VERSION")
```

The `-L` flag will  list all files including the ones in the directories which are symlinks. Unfortunately, other linux commands such as `find .`, `ls -R`, etc stop at the symlink without navigating into them to list further.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: So i ran the code and im getting no errors, but i cant fint the text file it should be generating (content.txt) i have my code on my desktop and the conetent.txt is not showing up, what do you think

Comment: So this might be deal with permissions: try two things: "echo {{your password}} | sudo -S ls -LR > content.txt" and also ssh it, via terminal and run "ls -LR" and view on your terminal that there is content being generated (and the command is functioning as expected). Could you please do these two things and let me know what happens? :0)

Comment: Also, you might need to check if you need to  escape your string. (Also know it will generate the string on the machine you're ssh-ing into!)Please let me know if you have any questions!